# State Machine Workflow designer for Windows WF

Tags: workflow-foundation, state-machine

I want a designer for State Machine Windows WF, I find a sample code from microsoft and host visual studio desginer of Sequence Workflow in a Windows app, but I can't use it for State Machine ,
Is there any desginer for State Machine or can I host visual studio in another windows app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same hostable designer control supports both sequential and state machine workflow editing. It's mentioned on here with some examples of how to save and restore the layout of the state nodes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx

Comment: Many Thanks, Is there any Web based desginer? ( or re-hosting sample)

Comment: You could wrap the standard designer in an ActiveX control so it could be hosted in a web page. But there might be very little point to doing that - the download would be huge for users who don't already have .NET Framework 3.5.